# How to change SKScene size when rotate Device?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

Im trying to make a SKScene that renders a fractal tree using a recursive functions. Each branch is a `SKShapeNode`. The initial line length should always be a percentage of the scene height. I have a computed variable used for the first line length that currently returns `frame.height * 0.3`. My problem is that I want to keep the percentage right when the device is rotated. I added the following code to my ViewController:

```swift
    var scene: FractalTreeScene!
    override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        if fromInterfaceOrientation == .landscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == .landscapeRight {
            scene.size = CGSize(width: 1337, height: 750)
        } else {
            scene.size = CGSize(width: 750, height: 1337)
        }
        scene.drawTree()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            scene = FractalTreeScene()
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {
                scene.size = CGSize(width: 1337, height: 750)
            } else {
                scene.size = CGSize(width: 750, height: 1337)
            }
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
```

I then launched the app in portrait and it all looked fine, then I tried  rotating to landscape and the size didn't change at all(I added print(size) to update function on scene). I then rotated back to portrait and the size changed to what it should have changed when in landscape rotating back to landscape got me the portrait size.

I then restarted the app in portrait rotated to landscape right and as expected the size didn't change then I rotated to landscape left and the size changed to the right value.

So apparently the codes work but the size only really gets changed when I rotate scene after changing it. Is there a way to make this change instantly? or maybe is there a better way of changing scene size when rotating? or even is there a way to maintain line size and position relative to screen without changing scene size?

Comment: Please read up on guard let parm .., vs if let parm. The latter will not make the parm accessible outside the scope of the if-clause. guard will

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the code to :

```swift
 var scene: FractalTreeScene!
    override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
            scene.size = CGSize(width: 1337, height: 750)
        } else {
            scene.size = CGSize(width: 750, height: 1337)
        }
        scene.drawTree()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            scene = FractalTreeScene()
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape{
                scene.size = CGSize(width: 1337, height: 750)
            } else {
                scene.size = CGSize(width: 750, height: 1337)
            }
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was going to tell you the problem is you were using `fromInterfaceOrientation` meaning your previous orientation